# CSS3 : Alternating row colors?

Tags: html, css

To alternate row color in a table using css i use :

```
p:nth-child(odd)
{
    background:#ff0000;
}
p:nth-child(even)
{
    background:#0000ff;
}
```

can anyone please explain me what's the "odd" and "even" mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div>
    <p></p> <!-- odd child,  1st -->
    <p></p> <!-- even child, 2nd -->
    <p></p> <!-- odd child,  3rd -->
    <p></p> <!-- even child, 4th -->
    <p></p> <!-- odd child,  5th -->
    <p></p> <!-- even child, 6th -->
    <p></p> <!-- odd child,  7th -->
</div>
```

Check [these examples](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd) about `odd`/`even` or [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrctk/1/)

Also, you can use it with any tag that contains squence of elements...

Answer (score 0):

odd: children number 1, 3, 5, 7.....
even: children number 2, 4, 6, 8.....

Answer (score 0):

Odd column ids are 1,3,5,7,.... and even column ids are 2,4,6,8,...

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list item for example, `:odd` will refer to all instances of the element that appear at 1,3,5,7 and so on, `:even`, 2,4,6,8 etc.

In this case, `foo` and `foo2` will be considered `:odd`, `bar` and `bar2` considered `even`

```
 - foo
 - bar
 - foo2
 - bar2
```

Answer (score 0):

It refers to row numbers... If the row is `even` (divisible by 2) it uses `background:#0000ff;`, else if the row number is `odd` (not divisible by 2) it uses `background:#ff0000;`.

Answer (score 0):

Odd is every row number not divisible by 2 and even is every other row.

Since the first row has the index 1 and 1 modulo 2 isn't 0 it will have the red background and the second row has the index 2 and 2 modulo 2 is 0 so it's blue.